# Bootstrap - pull and push

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-grid

I have two divs on my productlistpage: one with filters and one with products. On mobile and tablet i need to change the current order of the divs, so the sidebar is above the products.

*Product-div:*

```
class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-md-push-3 col-lg-push-3"
```

*Sidebar-div:*

```
class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-md-pull-9 col-lg-pull-9 sidebar"
```

I have tried with bootstraps pull and push without luck. Is the best solution just to create a new div above the content of products and use boostraps hide on the sidebar?

Comment: Can you give us some more HTML code? Probably what you are looking for is the CSS property `order`.

Comment: push is to make a blank space on right or left, if you have 2 columns like here in the example, one is 9 second is 3, so there is no need to give `col-md-push-3 col-lg-push-3` go ahead and you can simply add `col-md-9 col-sm-12` only for prodcust div and `col-md-3 col-sm-12` for sidebar